# Phusion Passenger Standalone: How to pass a command line flag to ruby?

Tags: ruby, passenger, jruby

As part of a performance analysis, I'd like to run my rails app with several different rubies. All of them have the gem `passenger` (v5) installed and are able to run `passenger start`.

The question: How can I pass a flag (like `--1.8`) to my ruby interpreter? I'm using the version manager `rbenv`, but when I'm running

`ruby --1.8 -S passenger start`

using the interpreter `jruby-1.7.27`, the flag is non-persistant i.e. jruby does not run in the 1.8 compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can set an environment variable, which also applies to the instantiated passenger server:

```
env JRUBY_OPTS=--1.8 ruby -S passenger start
```

works like a charm.
See the [JRuby FAQ](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/FAQs) for further details.